# How to build my permit condition in each month?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

> An employee is entitled to 3 permits per month, if the employee
>   wants a fourth permit would have to wait until next month.

my table is the following:

Permissions

```
id           (int),
format       (text),
date_requested (date),
initial_date (date),
final_date   (date),
employe_id   (int)
```

the code of my condition:

```
deactivate: 0,



var cont = response.data.length;
              if(cont >= 3)
              {
                  this.deactivate = 1;
              }
              else{
                  this.deactivate = 0;
                  }
```

On my button added the following

```
<button type="button" v-bind:disabled="deactivate == 1" @click="AModal('employe.id)" class="btn btn-primary float-sm-right">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;New
                        </button>
```

In this part I can already restrict the permissions that are three.

I just want that next month you can add the 3 permits, but I can not find a way to do it, I hope you can help me.

Comment: what do you mean by next month, could you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Limit your dB query to only return results from this month where initial date is before the last day of this month and final date is more the first day of the month